# Laravel Google 2FA not triggering after login

Tags: laravel, google-2fa

I'm struggling one day on the 2FA implementation.
I can get the QR code and I can enable it successfully.
The problem is that after my login, the middleware seems bypass the 2FA check and there is no way to input the code.

I used this tutorial to proceed: `https://shouts.dev/articles/laravel-two-factor-authentication-with-google-authenticator#step1`

This is my routes/web.php file (I deleted all the routes not affected)

```
//HOME PAGE
Route::any('/', function () {
    return redirect('/home');
});

Route::any('home', 'Home@index')->name('home');



//LOGIN & SIGNUP
Route::get("/login", "Authenticate@logIn")->name('login');
Route::post("/login", "Authenticate@logInAction");
Route::get("/forgotpassword", "Authenticate@forgotPassword");
Route::post("/forgotpassword", "Authenticate@forgotPasswordAction");
Route::get("/signup", "Authenticate@signUp");
Route::post("/signup", "Authenticate@signUpAction");
Route::get("/resetpassword", "Authenticate@resetPassword");
Route::post("/resetpassword", "Authenticate@resetPasswordAction");

//LOGOUT
Route::any('logout', function () {
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/login');
});

Route::get('/redirect', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');


Route::group(['prefix'=>'2fa'], function(){
    Route::get('/','LoginSecurityController@show2faForm');
    Route::post('/generateSecret','LoginSecurityController@generate2faSecret')->name('generate2faSecret');
    Route::post('/enable2fa','LoginSecurityController@enable2fa')->name('enable2fa');
    Route::post('/disable2fa','LoginSecurityController@disable2fa')->name('disable2fa');

    // 2fa middleware
    Route::post('/2faVerify', function () {
        return redirect(URL()->previous());
    })->name('2faVerify')->middleware('2fa');
});

// test middleware
Route::get('/test_middleware', function () {
    return "2FA middleware work!";
})->middleware(['auth', '2fa']);
```

This is my application\app\Http\Middleware\LoginSecurityMiddleware.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Support\Google2FAAuthenticator;
use Closure;

class LoginSecurityMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $authenticator = app(Google2FAAuthenticator::class)->boot($request);

        if ($authenticator->isAuthenticated()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return $authenticator->makeRequestOneTimePasswordResponse();
    }
}
```

This is my application\app\Http\Controllers\LoginSecurityController.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\LoginSecurity;
use Auth;
use Hash;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginSecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show 2FA Setting form
     */
    public function show2faForm(Request $request){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $google2fa_url = "";
        $secret_key = "";

        if($user->loginSecurity()->exists()){
            $google2fa = (new \PragmaRX\Google2FAQRCode\Google2FA());
            $google2fa_url = $google2fa->getQRCodeInline(
                'AgileApp',
                $user->email,
                $user->loginSecurity->google2fa_secret
            );
            $secret_key = $user->loginSecurity->google2fa_secret;
        }

        $data = array(
            'user' => $user,
            'secret' => $secret_key,
            'google2fa_url' => $google2fa_url
        );

        return view('auth.2fa_settings')->with('data', $data);
    }

    /**
     * Generate 2FA secret key
     */
    public function generate2faSecret(Request $request){
        $user = Auth::user();
        // Initialise the 2FA class
        $google2fa = (new \PragmaRX\Google2FAQRCode\Google2FA());

        // Add the secret key to the registration data
        $login_security = LoginSecurity::firstOrNew(array('user_id' => $user->id));
        $login_security->user_id = $user->id;
        $login_security->google2fa_enable = 0;
        $login_security->google2fa_secret = $google2fa->generateSecretKey();
        $login_security->save();

        return redirect('/2fa')->with('success',"Secret key is generated.");
    }

    /**
     * Enable 2FA
     */
    public function enable2fa(Request $request){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $google2fa = (new \PragmaRX\Google2FAQRCode\Google2FA());

        $secret = $request->input('secret');
        $valid = $google2fa->verifyKey($user->loginSecurity->google2fa_secret, $secret);

        if($valid){
            $user->loginSecurity->google2fa_enable = 1;
            $user->loginSecurity->save();
            return redirect('2fa')->with('success',"2FA is enabled successfully.");
        }else{
            return redirect('2fa')->with('error',"Invalid verification Code, Please try again.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Disable 2FA
     */
    public function disable2fa(Request $request){
        if (!(Hash::check($request->get('current-password'), Auth::user()->password))) {
            // The passwords matches
            return redirect()->back()->with("error","Your password does not matches with your account password. Please try again.");
        }

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'current-password' => 'required',
        ]);
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->loginSecurity->google2fa_enable = 0;
        $user->loginSecurity->save();
        return redirect('/2fa')->with('success',"2FA is now disabled.");
    }
}
```

This is my application\app\Models\User.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Cache;
use DB;

class User extends Authenticatable {
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * @primaryKey string - primry key column.
     * @dateFormat string - date storage format
     * @guarded string - allow mass assignment except specified
     * @CREATED_AT string - creation date column
     * @UPDATED_AT string - updated date column
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
    protected $guarded = ['id', 'type'];
    const CREATED_AT = 'created';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updated';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function loginSecurity()
    {
        //return $this->hasOne(LoginSecurity::class);
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\LoginSecurity');
    }

    /**
     * The tasks that are assigned to the user.
     */
    public function role() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Role', 'role_id', 'role_id');
    }


        /**
     * The tasks that are assigned to the user.
     */
    public function client() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Client', 'client_id', 'clientid');
    }

    /**
     * relatioship business rules:
     *         - the User can have many Notes
     *         - the Note belongs to one User
     *         - other Note can belong to other tables
     */
    public function notes() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Note', 'noteresource');
    }

    /**
     * The tasks that are assigned to the user.
     */
    public function assignedTasks() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Task', 'tasks_assigned', 'tasksassigned_userid', 'tasksassigned_taskid');
    }

    /**
     * The tasks that are assigned to the user.
     */
    public function assignedLeads() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Lead', 'leads_assigned', 'leadsassigned_userid', 'leadsassigned_leadid');
    }

    /**
     * The projects that are assigned to the user.
     */
    public function assignedProjects() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Project', 'projects_assigned', 'projectsassigned_userid', 'projectsassigned_projectid');
    }

    /**
     * users notifications
     */
    public function notifications() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EventTracking', 'eventtracking_userid', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * Always encrypt the password before saving to database
     */
    public function setFPasswordAttribute($value) {
        return bcrypt($value);
    }

    /**
     * count: users projects
     * - always reclaulated fresh. No session data here
     */
    public function getCountProjectsAttribute() {

    }

    /**
     * count: users unread notifications
     * @usage auth()->user()->count_unread_notifications
     */
    public function getCountUnreadNotificationsAttribute() {
        //use notifications relationship (above)
        return $this->notifications->where('eventtracking_status', 'unread')->count();
    }

    /**
     * users full name ucfirst
     */
    public function getFullNameAttribute() {
        return ucfirst($this->first_name) . ' ' . ucfirst($this->last_name);
    }

    /**
     * get the users avatar. if it does not exist return the default avatar
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAvatarAttribute() {
        return getUsersAvatar($this->avatar_directory, $this->avatar_filename);
    }

    /**
     * check if the user has the role of 'administrator'
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsAdminAttribute() {
        if (strtolower($this->role->role_id) == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * check if the user has the role of 'master'
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsMasterAttribute() {
        if (strtolower($this->role->role_id) == 6) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * check if the user has the type 'client'
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsClientAttribute() {
        if (strtolower($this->type) == 'client') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * check if the user has the type 'client' and also account owner
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsClientOwnerAttribute() {
        if (strtolower($this->type) == 'client') {
            if ($this->account_owner == 'yes') {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * check if the user has the type 'team'
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getIsTeamAttribute() {
        if (strtolower($this->type) == 'team') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * return 'team' or 'contacts'for use in url's like
     * updating user preferences
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getTeamOrContactAttribute() {
        if (strtolower($this->type) == 'team') {
            return 'team';
        }
        return 'contacts';
    }

    /**
     * get the 'name' of this users role
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserRoleAttribute() {
        return strtolower($this->role->role_name);
    }

    /**
     * format last seen date
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCarbonLastSeenAttribute() {
        if ($this->last_seen == '' || $this->last_seen == null) {
            return '---';
        }
        return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($this->last_seen)->diffForHumans();
    }

    /**
     * is the user online now. Activity is set in the General middle
     *  [usage] if($user->is_online)
     * @return string
     */
    public function getisOnlineAttribute() {
        return Cache::has('user-is-online-' . $this->id);
    }

    /**
     * get the users preferred left menu position. If none is
     * defined, return the default system seting
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLeftMenuPositionAttribute() {

        //none logged in users
        if (!auth()->check()) {
            return config('system.settings_system_default_leftmenu');
        }

        //logged in user
        if ($this->pref_leftmenu_position != '') {
            return $this->pref_leftmenu_position;
        } else {
            return config('system.settings_system_default_leftmenu');
        }
    }

    /**
     * get the users preferred stats panels position. If none is
     * defined, return the default system seting
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStatsPanelPositionAttribute() {

        //none logged in users
        if (!auth()->check()) {
            return config('system.settings_system_default_statspanel');
        }

        //logged in user
        if ($this->pref_statspanel_position != '') {
            return $this->pref_statspanel_position;
        } else {
            return config('system.settings_system_default_statspanel');
        }
    }

    /**
     * check if the user has any permissions to add content, so that we can display the red add button in top nav
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getCanAddContentAttribute() {

        $count = 0;

        //add
        $count += ($this->role->role_clients >= 2) ? 1 : 0;
        $count += ($this->role->role_contacts >= 2) ? 1 : 0;
        $count += ($this->role->role_invoices >= 2) ? 1 : 0;
        $count += ($this->role->role_estimates >= 2) ? 1 : 0;
        $count += ($this->role->role_items >= 2) ? 1 : 0;
        $count += ($this->role->role_tasks >= 2) ? 1 : 0;
        $count += ($this->role->role_projects >= 2) ? 1 : 0;
        $count += ($this->role->role_leads >= 2) ? 1 : 0;
        $count += ($this->role->role_expenses >= 2) ? 1 : 0;
        $count += ($this->role->role_team >= 2) ? 1 : 0;
        $count += ($this->role->role_tickets >= 2) ? 1 : 0;
        $count += ($this->role->role_knowledgebase >= 2) ? 1 : 0;

        return ($count > 0) ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Query Scope
     * Left join the client table (used if needed)
     * @param object $query automatically passed by eloquent
     * @return bool
     */
    public function scopeLeftjoinClients($query) {
        $query->leftJoin('clients', function ($leftJoin) {
            $leftJoin->on('clients.client_id', '=', 'users.clientid');
        });
    }

}
```

This is my application\app\Support\Google2FAAuthenticator.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Support;

use PragmaRX\Google2FALaravel\Support\Authenticator;

class Google2FAAuthenticator extends Authenticator
{
    protected function canPassWithoutCheckingOTP()
    {
        if ($this->getUser()->loginSecurity == null)
            return true;

        return
            !$this->getUser()->loginSecurity->google2fa_enable ||
            !$this->isEnabled() ||
            $this->noUserIsAuthenticated() ||
            $this->twoFactorAuthStillValid();
    }

    protected function getGoogle2FASecretKey()
    {
        $secret = $this->getUser()->loginSecurity->{$this->config('otp_secret_column')};

        if (is_null($secret) || empty($secret)) {
            throw new InvalidSecretKey('Secret key cannot be empty.');
        }

        return $secret;
    }

}
```

This is my application\app\Models\LoginSecurity.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class LoginSecurity extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id'
    ];
    
    public function user()
    {
        //return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

This is my application\config\google2fa.php file

```
<?php

return [

    /*
     * Enable / disable Google2FA.
     */
    'enabled' => env('OTP_ENABLED', true),

    /*
     * Lifetime in minutes.
     *
     * In case you need your users to be asked for a new one time passwords from time to time.
     */
    'lifetime' => env('OTP_LIFETIME', 0), // 0 = eternal

    /*
     * Renew lifetime at every new request.
     */
    'keep_alive' => env('OTP_KEEP_ALIVE', true),

    /*
     * Auth container binding.
     */
    'auth' => 'auth',

    /*
     * Guard.
     */
    'guard' => '',

    /*
     * 2FA verified session var.
     */
    'session_var' => 'google2fa',

    /*
     * One Time Password request input name.
     */
    'otp_input' => 'one_time_password',

    /*
     * One Time Password Window.
     */
    'window' => 1,

    /*
     * Forbid user to reuse One Time Passwords.
     */
    'forbid_old_passwords' => false,

    /*
     * User's table column for google2fa secret.
     */
    'otp_secret_column' => 'google2fa_secret',

    /*
    * One Time Password View.
    */
    'view' => 'auth.2fa_verify',

    /*
     * One Time Password error message.
     */
    'error_messages' => [
        'wrong_otp'       => "The 'One Time Password' typed was wrong.",
        'cannot_be_empty' => 'One Time Password cannot be empty.',
        'unknown'         => 'An unknown error has occurred. Please try again.',
    ],

    /*
     * Throw exceptions or just fire events?
     */
    'throw_exceptions' => env('OTP_THROW_EXCEPTION', true),

    /*
     * Which image backend to use for generating QR codes?
     *
     * Supports imagemagick, svg and eps
     */
    'qrcode_image_backend' => \PragmaRX\Google2FALaravel\Support\Constants::QRCODE_IMAGE_BACKEND_SVG,

];
```

This is the code I added on my application\app\Http\Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [

        '2fa' => \App\Http\Middleware\LoginSecurityMiddleware::class,
```

And this is my migration file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateLoginSecuritiesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('login_securities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->boolean('google2fa_enable')->default(false);
            $table->string('google2fa_secret')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('login_securities');
    }
}
```

The system generate correctly the QR, I can add the QR to Google Authenticator and I can receive the code confirmation.
After login, nothing happen.